# Can't send embed message on join

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

No idea why it won't work, the exact code worked on my old bot. Code:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("**Please be sure to read our rules carefully thanks**")
      .setAuthor("Welcome to BACKUP")
      .setColor(3447003)
      .setDescription("Please enjoy your stay")
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
      client.channels.get('505107608391254030').send({embed});
  })
}
```

The thing that confuses me most, is that if I replace that code with this code, it works fine.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.guild.channels.get('505107608391254030').send("This works, but embed does not, fix it boi, line 102"); 
});
```

(On the code that did not work, I tried: `client.channels.get, member.channels.get, member.guild.channels.get, client.guild.channels.get`

Comment: Does it display any error?

Comment: No error at all.

Comment: Try using `member.guild.channels.get('id').send("test content", {embed})` to see if it sends it

Comment: Did not work, still no error.

Comment: Have you tried checking if the function runs in the first place? Try putting a `console.log` at the top, before declaring `Discord`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you are finding the channel, `client.channels.get` <del>isn't a method.</del> doesn't work in this situation for reasons I'm not aware of

You have to use `client.guilds.get(GUILD_ID).channels.get(CHANNEL_ID).send({embed});`

Comment: That worked, thanks. Now it says `message` is not defined lmao and I have no idea how to define it.

Comment: Where are you using it? `message` will only be defined in an client.on("message")

Comment: In the line `.setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL` everyone I have asked for help just say "you need to define message" but I have no idea how to define it in my case

Comment: As I said in my previous comment '`message` will only be defined in an client.on("message")'. Clearly you are in `client.on("guildMemberAdd")`. `member.user.avatarURL` will get you what you want.

To explain slightly: `message` refers to the message that was sent, but if someone was added to the server, no message was sent. The only information we have was the member that was added, from there we can get the user object associated with that member, and then get the attributes from there

Comment: I joined a Discord support group to try and get help, I was overthinking, I had it as `member.user.avatarURL` before posting here, but it would not work, I tried changing embed author icon using the same `member.user.avatarURL` and it worked. So my issue is that `.setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL` is not working. but it works in the .setAuthor

Comment: Solved. It would not work because the avatar was high resolution, confirmed with lower res avatar.

Comment: Ah, okay thanks for the update. I'm glad it's working now :)